# In AS3, how can you dynamically add operations to a WebService object?

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

Let's say you have a WebService object defined inside an fx:Declarations tag in MXML with some operations in it, along with response and fault handlers for those operations.  Now let's say you want to pass that WebService into the constructor of another object, which will then add an operation to the WebService at runtime, along with its own response and fault handler functions for that new operation.

For example:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:WebService id="ws" fault="Alert.show('failure')">
        <s:operation
            name="Op1"
            resultFormat="object"
            result="WebOp1(event);"
            fault="WebFaultOp1()"
        />
    </s:WebService>
</fx:Declarations>

.
.
.
        var a:A = new A(ws);
```

and:

```
public class A
{
    private var m_ws:WebService;

    public function A(pWS:WebService)
    {
        m_ws = pWS;
        m_ws.Op2 = new Operation();
        m_ws.Op2.resultFormat = "object";
        m_ws.Op2.result = WebOp2(event);
        m_ws.Op2.fault = WebFaultOp2(event);
    }

    private function WebOp2(pEvent:ResultEvent):void
    {
    }

    private function WebFaultOp2(pEvent:FaultEvent):void
    {
    }
}
```

How could this be done?  I'm willing to use MXML if I have to, but what I'm really trying to avoid here is something like having to create two separate WebService objects that just share the same WSDL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like that:

```
var operation:Operation = new Operation(webService, 'noName'); // mx.rpc.soap.mxml.Operation
operation.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onResult);
operation.addEventListener(FaultEvent.Fault, onFault);
webService.operations['noName']=operation;
```

Comment: It seems to be mostly working, but I'm getting a fault from it.  event.fault.faultString == [MessagingError message='The MessageAgent's destination must be set to send messages.'].  I'm only seeing obscure references to how to fix that problem so far.